# Excel - # of characters formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to write a formula that will add a zero to the end of a string of numbers if they are less than 9 digits long.  When I pull in the data, I either have a 9 digit number (which I want) or an 8 digit number (which needs the added zero at the end).  I was thinking something like this formula below but not sure how to write it.

If(A1=9digits,A1,A1&0).  I just can't get the correct formula to populate what I want.  All help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: are they actual numbers and not numbers stored as text?

Answer (score 0):

Use LEN:

```
=IF(LEN(A1)=8,A1*10,A1)
```

Comment: Perfect. thank you!